# NodeJS - securely connect to external redis server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, proxy, redis, server

On my **main server**, I fetch data from an external/seperate **redis server** which is accessed through an api `https://localhost:7000/api/?token=****`  which works. However `token` and api is not secure. And since I want to have **redis server** to be separate, this technique isn't suited for my case.

In my case I want to have 2 independent servers **A** and **B**.
 **A** should load data from **B** without using an api or url call... Instead it should use **port** (e.g. `//server:123`). This way server **B** can only be accessed from **A**.

I want this approach to work for both development and production. AWS has "Server Groups" I believe, but that's production only...

---

So is there a way to create this kind of connection with nodejs? I also want to know if this is only possible having a running server already, since I don't have one yet.

*Note: In case you are wondering, I use redis to store private keys for encryption, so I need a secure, separate server which can be controlled independently*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear what you're trying to do since accessing data from another server without using an API does not really make sense.  Anything you do to access it is some type of API.

If you want to make it so that only server A can access server B, then you have a number of choices to make that secure:

1. Require authentication whenever server B is accessed and make it so that only server A has those authentication credentials.
2. Assuming server A and server B are in your same server infrastructure, put the server B API on a port that is not available to the outside world, but is only available from within your server infrastructure (this usually involves picking a port that your firewall to the outside is blocking access to).
3. On server A, only accept connections on its API from the specific IP address of server B.

You can even implement more than one of these options at once.  For example, it's not uncommon to use 1) and 2) together.

Comment: Thanks, for option 2 - as I understand, server B hasn't got any url access, so I need to configure server A to access server B via port. How would you do that in development, since I don't have a production/paid server which can be configured? In this case do I need to download 'Ubuntu' server on my computer?

Comment: @aloha_mate - What do you think "access via port" is that isn't a server or doesn't use an URL?  We can't help you if we don't know what that is.

Comment: sorry I meant a server that is "not available to the outside world". So do you suggest downloading 'Ubuntu' localy to manage this?

Comment: @aloha_mate - I think you're confused about something, but I'm not sure quite what you're trying to do.  Your question mentions serverA and serverB.  That's what I'm trying to answer.  I don't know what downloading Ubuntu locally has to do with how serverA accesses serverB.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey, thanks. What do you mean by: "Assuming server A and server B are in your same server infrastructure" technically?

Comment: @user6227254 - I mean that they're in the same network and behind the same firewall so the network can be configured to allow them to communicate with one another on a given port, but the outside world is blocked from that specific access by a firewall (thus giving you access from serverA to serverB, but security from the outside world accessing serverB).  If your firewall only allows public access on port 80 or 443, then you can configure serverB to run on port 4000 and serverA can contact its API on port 4000, but the public cannot because the firewall blocks access to port 4000 for public.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, I am going to use AWS. So do I need to make https request using the `domain + port` or `ip address + port`? I have read about configuring and it says that I can make server **B** listen to private ip of server of **A**. But how would you send a request? And does server **B** needs to be offline, for security reasons?

Comment: @user6227254 - I don't follow what you mean when you say: "make server B listen to private ip of server of A".  What I meant was that you can use either a private IP or a private port for one server to contact another.

Comment: @jfriend00 my bad. If I would use a private IP instead of private port, can I still make a request using https? And what technique is more secure and favoured?

Comment: @user6227254 -  Yes, you can do a request to `https://xxx.yyy.zzz/whatever` where `xxx.yyy.zzz` is a private IP address as long as your other server is listening on that private IP address and you have access to that private IP address.  As to what is more secure and favored, that depends on lots and lots of details of your security, network layout, firewalls, etc... which are not disclosed here.  Configured properly, that technique should be perfectly secure.

Comment: @jfriend00 Last question, so when I make an `https` request from server **A** using the "private ip", the server checks if any connection is listening to the request.  If not it will make a request using DNS? Is this correct?

Comment: @user6227254 - No.  When you already have a server's IP address, there is no reason to use DNS because the function of DNS is to get a server's IP address.  And, none of this has anything to do with https either.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, so the request happens on server side, despite http?

Comment: @user6227254 - I have no idea what that last comment means.  If serverA contacts serverB via an http request, that's entirely server side communication between two servers.  Servers can send or receive http requests. Browsers can only send http requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know it's been a long time, but how combining "choices" 1 and 2 together, make the network more secure? If server **A** was hacked then network is already compromised... Is there a specific attack, if so please name it - I want to research it :)

Comment: @user6227254 - Restricting access to B so the outside world cannot access it, absolutely makes it more secure from a wide variety of attacks.  And, requiring credentials to access B makes it secure in case there was a problem with the previous restriction or if there are rogue agents behind the firewall.  So, either of the two options can compensate for a weakness in the other, thus making the two of them together more secure than either one individually.

Comment: @user6227254 - It's like having two levels of security where an attacker must get through both before they can get in.  Analogous to having two separate locks on the front door where both keys are required in order to get in.  If any one key is compromised, the door is still secure.

Answer (score 1):

Stunnel is built for that ! basically speaking  it's a vpn ! but not for machines for ports ! it's a bit complicated , you will have to deal with certificates and a couple of other things (config both servers...) but once it's done it's a breeze to launch and reuse  (just launch a file)  give it a try !

and see this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ssl-tunnel-using-stunnel-on-ubuntu

you should also consider adding an ip table rule at the database server to allow access to your server only.

Edit:

Keep in mind that redis was designed to be used in a trusted environment . This means that the security layer will not be redis itself but a third party software that u'll need to setup.

For dev purpose no need to make this bulletproof. And even if you want to , it's kinda hard to do . because the security of your app is mainly depending on the infrastructure of the company that will host your app.

That being said , if you want to secure a redis instance in a localhost environment . a rule at the ip table allowing only the localhost to access your port 6379 will be suffcient.

The other thing that could compromise the security of your redis DB is the app itself . An important aspect of this is to validate EVERYTHING , it should be a good start.

Finally if you want to dive a bit deeper take a look at this link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04

hope this helps !